# MySQL TIMEDIFF(DATE, DATETIME)

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have two columns in MySQL database.

One is in DATE format like 2014-01-26, another one is in DATETIME format: 2014-01-25 17:19:07.

I need to apply TIMEDIFF(2014-01-26, 2014-01-25 17:19:07)  function, but it requires both variables are in DATETIME format. How can I convert 2014-01-26 to 2014-01-26 00:00:00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always cast a Date to a datetime

`select timediff(cast(<yourDateColumn> as Datetime), <yourDatetimeColumn>)`

But I'm not even really sure that you need to cast (depending on your mysql version), I may misunderstand the doc, but we can read

> Prior to MySQL 5.1.18, when DATE values are compared with DATETIME
>   values, the time portion of the DATETIME value is ignored, or the
>   comparison could be performed as a string compare. Starting from MySQL
>   5.1.18, a DATE value is coerced to the DATETIME type by adding the time portion as '00:00:00'. To mimic the old behavior, use the CAST()
>   function to cause the comparison operands to be treated as previously.
>   For example:

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**date_format()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
mysql> select 
TIMEDIFF(date_format('2014-01-26','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '2014-01-25 17:19:07') 
as diff;
+----------+
| diff     |
+----------+
| 06:40:53 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select date_format('2014-01-26','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as date;
+---------------------+
| date                |
+---------------------+
| 2014-01-26 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```